# What languages are available in "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World! Judgment on this Greedy Game!"?

Tags: konosuba-judgement-greedy-game

I was thinking on purchasing the PS4 edition of "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World! Judgment on this Greedy Game!" but I don't know if it contains any language other than Japanese.

What languages are available in "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World! Judgment on this Greedy Game!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [linked](https://www.yesasia.com/global/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%A0%E6%99%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E7%A5%9D%E7%A6%8F%E3%82%92-%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%B7%E5%AE%AE%E3%81%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E5%86%92%E9%99%BA%E8%80%85%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-%E9%80%9A%E5%B8%B8%E7%89%88-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E7%89%88/1070149677-0-0-0-ja/info.html) by BlueRaja, it is only available in Japanese. You can cross-reference with [the official site](http://www.entergram.co.jp/konosuba/product/) too, which is only in Japanese.